# Is it possible to align the boxes similar to the design using CSS float properties?

Tags: css, css-float

[this design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPRfQ.png)

I have designed this using postioning element and Z-index.Now I want to solve this using float element of CSS.

Comment: float property is used for same plane alignment of elements. If you want to change stacking or vertical ordering of elements, then z-index is preferred.

Comment: i have done this with Z-index already but cannot do with float